# Python regex extract number from string

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract a number from a large html file with python.
My idea was to use regex like this:

```
import re
text = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
try:
    found = re.search('AAA(.+?)ZZZ', text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    found = ''

found
```

But unfortunately i'm not used to regex and i fail to adapt this example to extract `0,54125` from:

```
(...)<div class="vk_ans vk_bk">0,54125 count id</div>(...)
```

Is there an other way to extract the number or could some one help me with the regex?

Comment: Extract the contents of the tag you need with BeautifulSoup and then just split the string and get Item #0.

Comment: Do not use regex for HTML parsing: there are enough tools more suitable for this purpose, e.g. BeautifulSoup, lxml.html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want output `0,54125`(or `\d+,\d+`), then you need to set some conditions for the output.

From the following input,

```
 (...)<div class="vk_ans vk_bk">0,54125 count id</div>(...)
```

If you want to extract `0,54125`, it seems you can try several regexs like follows,

```
(?<=\>)\d+,\d+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/145)

or,

```
(?<=\<div class=\"vk_ans vk_bk\"\>)\d+,\d+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/146)

, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can replace some characters in your text before searching it. For example, to capture numbers like `12,34` you can do this:

```
text = 'gfgfdAAA12,34ZZZuijjk'
try:
    text = text.replace(',', '')
    found = re.search('AAA(\d+)ZZZ', text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    found = ''

print found
# 1234
```

If you need to capture the digits inside a line, you can make your pattern more general, like this:

```
text = '<div class="vk_ans vk_bk">0,54125 count id</div>'
text = text.replace(',', '')
found = re.search('(\d+)', text).group(1)

print found
# 054125
```